# Calculate formula for $n^{th}$ power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I find a formula for the $n^{th}$ power of the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}
  1&2\\
  3&4
\end{pmatrix}?
$$

Is there a way to do this for all matrices?

Comment: HINT: diagonalize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Suppose a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable as $A = Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$. Then $$A^n = A \cdot A \cdot A \cdots A = Q\Lambda \color{red}{Q^{-1} Q} \Lambda \color{red}{Q^{-1} Q} \Lambda \color{red}{Q^{-1}} \cdots \color{red}{Q} \Lambda Q^{-1}.$$

What happens with the red terms?

Answer (score 2):

To find the eigenvalues: $(1-x)(4-x) - 3\cdot 2 = 4 - 5x + x^2 - 6 = 0 \iff x^2-5x - 2 = 0$. Can you then diagonalize it ?

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{5-\sqrt{33}}{2}&0\\0&\frac{5+\sqrt{33}}{2}\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: What do I do from here?

Comment: That makes it harder...

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't understand.

Comment: Then $A^n = BD^nB^{-1}$